# Percent change projected on a single columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to figure out how to project a percent variation change on a given starting amount.

To be clear, I have a dataframe which contains for each date the daily percent change.
I would like to apply this percent change on a starting value in this case 100 to see its evolution over time.
I have already customized the daily variation to ease the calculation as follow:
Customized variation = 1 + Daily Variation/100

Amount at 100 (first row last columns is given) and this is the columns I can't find the formula to get the result

[Expected Result :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bw77.png)

I have tried many way with Pandas but it looks like it doesn't want to execute the shift on Amount columns.

I pass to my function  a Pandas Serie containing the date and the daily variation in percent.
Then I calculate the daily Var customised as follow:
`df_col_actif_var['daily_var_custo'] = (1 + df_col_actif_var/100)`

And finally I try to build up the last column containing the expected results:
`df_col_actif_var['std'] = df_col_actif_var['std'].shift(1) * (df_col_actif_var['daily_var_custo'])`

But doesn't works

Please Help !

Comment: Refrain from showing your dataframe as an image.   Your question needs a minimal reproducible example consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for best practices related to Pandas questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use:

```
df['Amount'] = (df['Daily Variation']
                    .shift(-1).cumsum()
                    .add(100).shift(1, fill_value=100))
print(df)

# Output
    Date  Daily Variation  Customized Variation  Amount
0  Day 1            -0.75                0.9925  100.00
1  Day 2             1.02                1.1020  101.02
2  Day 3            -0.19                0.9981  100.83
3  Day 4            -0.42                0.9958  100.41
4  Day 5            -0.53                0.9947   99.88
```

Step by step:

```
# shift to remove -0.75
>>> out = df['Daily Variation'].shift(-1)
0    1.02
1   -0.19
2   -0.42
3   -0.53
4     NaN

# compute cumulative sum
>>> out = out.cumsum()
0    1.02
1    0.83
2    0.41
3   -0.12
4     NaN

# add your base value 100
>>> out = out.add(100)
0    101.02
1    100.83
2    100.41
3     99.88
4       NaN

# shift back to align values and fill the first row to your base value
>>> out = out.shift(1, fill_value=100)
0    100.00
1    101.02
2    100.83
3    100.41
4     99.88
```

Another way to do it but I prefer to chain methods :-). However the math is much more simpler.

```
df['Amount'] = df.loc[1:, 'Daily Variation']
df.loc[0, 'Amount'] = 100
df['Amount'] = df['Amount'].cumsum()
```

Comment: Brilliant ! That's working fine. Thanks a lot for your help. Can you please explain how Pandas do the math step by step with this formula

Comment: @Max. I updated my answer. Can you check it please? Is it clear enough?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the time you took to explain me your answer in details. I really appreciate  :)